# I implement {% csrf_token%} in my Django templates, but the token appears in the browser

Tags: django, forms, csrf-token

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8obW.png)i am very new to django. i am trying to create a login form in django but when i write the csrf_token line after the  tag it is showing in the browser view. everything is very confusing for me i don't know what to do. the tutorial that i watch on youtube only pass the csrf_token but don't say anything much.

{% csrf_token %}
            
                
                    Email
                
                
                                     
            
                
                    Password
                
                
            
            
                
                    Sign In
                
            
            Change Password

this is a very simple form that i styled using tailwindcss and the csrf token is being shown. also my app has other errors. it does not run on the development server

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit your settings.py? Did you put `{% csrf_token %}` inside `<form></form>` ? 3 things comes to my mind is:

1. check your settings.py for `MIDDLEWARE` and check if you have`'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'`.
2. Check your template to see if you placed `{% csrf_token %}` inside your form.
3. Check settings.py `TEMPLATES` section `BACKEND` if you have changed template engine. If you are using a custom template engine make sure it supports rendering this.